# Debugging uploading picture files into a folder

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. And I have copied and pasted the code for both the PHP and the HTML. And in a folder, I have `upload.html`, `php.ini` (with `file_uploads = On`), `upload.php` and a folder called `uploads` where all the uploaded files are supposed to go in, I think.

And when I press submit, everything seems to work, namely, the success message is echoed, `"The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded."`. However, no file seems to appear inside of the `uploads` folder.

Also, when I try to upload the same file, I get the error message, `echo "Sorry, file already exists.";`, which is weird because I don't see the file in my `uploads` folder.

I am currently using FireFTP to store all my code and the files that I am uploading.

Here is my code for `upload.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `upload.php`:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Also, someone told me that PHP is a server side language. What does that actually mean? I tried to read some stuff online but its so full of so much jargon. Does it mean that I have to use something like FireFTP to be able to use languages like PHP?

And I can't just open up my textfile using chrome and be able to use PHP? Like, I right click my textfile containing my code and do "open with chrome"? Does this also have to do with web-hosting?

Comment: this is not working in live server ??

Comment: I didn't actually buy the domain, no. But, I am using webhosting plus FireFTP to run this code.

Comment: check file permeation of your site

Comment: What do you mean permeation?

Comment: 777 permeation **Read, Write, Execute**

Comment: I dont understand how you can use PHP without knowing what is a server side language... About `php.ini`, it has to be edited where your PHP is installed. Its must not be just a file containing the directive `file_uploads = on;`. Last but not least, have you any errors ? Add at the beginning of your `upload.php` script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. It forces PHP to show errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code**

```
   $file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $file_exts = array("jpg", "bmp", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $upload_exts = end(explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
                    if ((($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                    || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                    || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/png")
                    || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
                    && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 2000000)
                    && in_array($upload_exts, $file_exts))
                            {
                                if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
                                {
                                    header("Location:dashboard.php?err=imgpro1");
                                    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] . "<br>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $tempupname = time().$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
                                    $imgpathtostore="uploads/".$tempupname;
                                    $imgpathtostoreDB="uploads/".$tempupname;
                                    // Enter your path to upload file here
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $imgpathtostore);
                                    }
                                    }
                                    else
                                            {
                                                header("Location: index.php?err=imgpro");
                                            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `uploads` folder permission read, write and delete.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, how do I do this?

Comment: Open your c panel of your hosting server and find this folder and set permission.

Comment: When you delete this folder then again you need to set permission.

Comment: this is key difference on local server and hosting server. for this you need to set permission before anything you need to with folder file delete or even need to new adding.

Comment: I found it! However, there seems to have three options, owner, group, and public. For the owner section, all three are checked.